# Pass object from one fragment to another fragment and store received object in a Global object

Tags: android, interface

I wanted to PASS A MODEL OBJECT from Fragment1 to Fragment2using interface (Both fragments in the same activity).
I received that object in a public class of Fragment2. Now I want to save the received object as a Global variable of Fragment2. So that I can use it other methods of the same Fragment2. 
But... But...
when I try to use the global object in onCreateView(), 
getting NULL POINTER EXCEPTION.

```
In Fragment1, 
 1. Interface declaration 
interface CommunicatePricePlanCheckOutInterface {
        void sendDataToCheckout( SinglePricePlanModel singleModel );
    }
 2. Object of Interface
    CommunicatePricePlanCheckOutInterface  communicationObject;
 3. passing data using method of interface in, onCreateView()
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_price_plan, 
                     container,false);
        allSampleData = new ArrayList<>();
        mPricePlanContinueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { 
               if (getActivity() != null) {
                  communicationObject.sendDataToCheckout(
                  allSampleData.get(0));
               } 
            }
        }); 
        return view;
       }
In activity, 
 4. implementing the interface
       public class NavDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, 
         Fragment1.CommunicatePricePlanCheckOutInterface
 5. overriding interface method and in the method calling a public method of Fragment2. 
 @Override
    public void sendDataToCheckout(SinglePricePlanModel pricePlanModel ) {
        Fragment2 frag2 = new Fragment2();
        frag2.receivePlanData(pricePlanModel, mUserBasicInfo);

    }
In Fragment2, 
 6. Received 2 objects from Activity, I can use them in this method, but can not access those mSinglePricePlanModel, mUserBasicInfo objects outside this method, like onCreateView or onViewCreated. Getting Null Pointer Exception if I try to 
access.

public void receivePlanData(SinglePricePlanModel mSinglePricePlanModel , UserBasicInfo mUserBasicInfo ){ 
        this.mSinglePricePlanModel = mSinglePricePlanModel;
        this.mUserBasicInfo = mUserBasicInfo;
}
```

Comment: share your NPE error from logcat

Comment: why not using viewmodel? https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?gclid=Cj0KCQjw3PLnBRCpARIsAKaUbguyxXBEQF0JOs0WXnuUFBMqZ738yRjscsQeY_aG8i-5xjo4IgH8AhsaAspFEALw_wcB

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized your interface object? I don't see any initialization in your fragment, that could be causing the null pointer exception. Initialize it inside `onAttach` method in your fragment like this-

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {

    super.onAttach(context);

    if (context instanceof CommunicatePricePlanCheckOutInterface) {

        communicationObject = (CommunicatePricePlanCheckOutInterface) context;
    }
}
```

It should not give null pointer exception then. Refer to this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating) for more details.

Comment: I did that. Data is received in fragment2. But I can only access those data in a specific method of fragment2. I want to access those data from onCreateView or onViewCreated. But getting that exception thing

Comment: When a fragment is created, the `onAttach` method is called first. Then `onCreate` is called and finally `onCreateView` is called. Your method will always be called after that. If you want to use the variable inside `onCreate` or `onCreateView`, then make sure to call that method inside `onCreateView` first. Also attach the error log if possible, as it will make the problem clear.